# Combine "proximity searches" with "wildcard searches" in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

Is thera a way to combine "proximity searches" with "wildcard searches" in solr?

I would expect the equivalent of the following.

```
"jakarta apa*"~10
```

with results having both `"jakarta apache"~10` and `"jakarta apalache"~10` etc.

Comment: You'll have to [use the ComplexPhraseQueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser) to support inline wildcards - I'm not sure if it supports the proximity qualifier, but try it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use definetely complexphrase:

{!complexphrase inOrder=true}FieldName"jakarta apa*"~10

Comment: That works. But adding a `:` after fieldname: `{!complexphrase inOrder=true}title:"jakarta apa*"~10`